# Keyboard input timeout with visible countdown

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good evening,

I want keyboard input with visible timer (time to respond)

My code

```
import time
import sys

def initial_startup(t): 
    print('Do you want to continue?')
    global input
    input = input("Answer yes or no only:" + " ").lower()
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60) 
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs) 
        print(timer, end="\r") 
        time.sleep(1) 
        t -= 1

    if input == "yes" or input == "yup":
        print("\n\nThanks script is now starting\n\n")
    else:
        pass
        

    if input == "no" or input == "nope":
        print("\nOk as you wish, I'm stopping...\n")
        sys.exit(1)

    if timer == "00:01":
        print("Timeout! try again")
        sys.exit(1)

t = 4

initial_startup(int(t))
```

I'm trying to get keyboard input with timeout and also want to show time below answer yes or no:

Prints timer after input ..

Want this output.

```
Output:
Do you want to continue?
Answer yes or no: 
You have {timer} time left...

If input then continue else sys.exit which is already in code.
```

> Thank you so much for helping to improve this newbie!

Comment: It is a bad idea to write `input = input("Answer yes or no only:" + " ").lower()` because that changes the meaning of the builtin function `input` to be a arbitrary string, *throughout* your program (because `global`). That advice aside,  you will find it difficult to show a running timer while waiting for console input the way your code is doing it, because `input()` is *blocking*. That is, your program halts until the user presses Enter. To do what you want you need a GUI framework such as `Tk` or `wxpython` or `pygame`. All of those have steeper learning curves than you may expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To do this you need to move with cursor in the terminal depending on the operating system you are using, it is very tiring and it is not very solid to use the terminal in that way **(a static stdout would be easier and safer)**, what I would do it is an output of this kind obviously you have to use a **multithread programming** to be able to use the file descriptor simultaneously

```py
import time
import sys
import threading
import time
import sys


def get_input(t):
    global stop_threads

    while True:
        input_cmd = input().lower()

        if input_cmd == "yes" or input_cmd == "yup":
            print("\n\nThanks script is now starting\n\n")
            break
        elif input_cmd == "no" or input_cmd == "nope":
            print("\nOk as you wish, I'm stopping...\n")
            break

    stop_threads = True


def initial_startup(t):

    print('Do you want to continue?')
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_input, args=(t,), daemon=True)
    t1.start()
    while t:
        global stop_timeout
        global stop_threads

        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)

        prompt = "You have %s time left...  Answer yes or no only: " % timer
        print(prompt)

        sys.stdout.write("\x1b[1A")  # cursor up one line
        sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2K")  # delete the last line

        if stop_threads:
            sys.exit(1)
        time.sleep(1)

        t -= 1

        if timer == "00:01":
            sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2K")  # delete the last line
            print("Timeout! try again")
            sys.exit(1)


stop_threads = False
stop_timeout = False
t = 4
initial_startup(int(t))
```

Output

```py
Do you want to continue?
You have 00:02 time left...  Answer yes or no only:

Ok as you wish, I'm stopping...
```

```py
Do you want to continue?
You have 00:02 time left...  Answer yes or no only:
Timeout! try again
```

```py
Do you want to continue?
You have 00:05 time left...  Answer yes or no only:

Thanks script is now starting
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well but when i hit enter input => yes it prints "thanks staring" but again starts counting what to do? It counts until 0 then ends but it should stop counting after input and should start executing code below but it didn't does that.

Comment: I did not understand what the bug is, can you explain yourself better maybe by inserting the output in the comment please?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CqqCSz47
After input Yes, code stopped didn't executed further.